# Hide Time in Date Type

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc

i want to hide time and show only the date like this(DD/MM/YYYY). I Tried with many way :

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dmcv.ToString()) %>
<%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dmcv.ToString("DD/MM/YYYY")) %>
<%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dmcv.Date.ToShortDateString()) %>
```

But i'm getting always same error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: The models can only be used with expressions access field of homeownership, the index of one-dimensional array or custom indexer single parameter.

I'm really missing something simple :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DisplayTemplates require a simple property expression. You could not use the DisplayTemplate and simply render the value directly:

```
@item.Dmcv.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

Or, you could create a new DisplayTemplate (partial view) for DateTime named Date:

```
@model DateTime
@Model.ToShortDateString()
```

And then change your view to use the new template:

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dmcv.Date, "Date") %>
```